# Magento- Create a product, such that no existing coupons is valid for that product

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, coupon, coupon-codes

I have around custom coupon codes generated for various type of offers and free shipment.

All my products are given a price and reduced price to buy for the user. And further discounts are applicable after applying coupon code.

Now i need to create a product with much reduced price than the previous products, so that no new/existing coupons must be invalid on that products.

Is that possible in magento to create a product that disallows the coupon code.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** and **No**,

**Yes** you can achieve it by putting product id in exclude list of all promo rules. if you have got many rules created, you need to update all manually, or through some upgrade script. e.g if product id x NOT FOUND IN cart

**No**, by default it's not possible to specify  while creating product that it should disallow coupon discount.